# Proof algebraic number fields Janusz, implies that every dedekind Ring is principal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

The book is Algebraic number fields,

The ring $R$ is a Dedekind ring and $\mathcal{U}$ is a ideal of $R$.[image] Janusz

The first four lemmas is completely clear to me, the While i can't understand the last corollary.

For example if $B$ is Dedekind Ring, then this implies that $R$ have a finite number of prime ideals is principal. Clearly is incorrect.

Is there an error in this corollary?

Thank you all.

Comment: $B$ has dimension zero; it can't be Dedekind.

Comment: Why $B$ has dimension zero?

Comment: _Every_ prime ideal is maximal.  Note that this is very different from the Dedekind condition, which is that $(0)$ is a non-maximal prime, and that every non-zero prime is maximal.

Comment: For example lemma 3.6 use that $B$ is Noetherian.
Corollary applies with $B$ Dedekind.
Lemma 3.8 is valid in any  commutative ring. I'm confused. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand why you keep saying that $B$ is Dedekind.  $B$ is a commutative ring, and it's noetherian, but it's not Dedekind, and the corollary certainly does not apply to Dedekind rings.

Comment: One clarification: $\mathfrak{U}$ should be a non-zero ideal.  Since $R$ is a domain of dimension $1$, it should follow immediately that $B=R/\mathfrak{U}$ is dimension zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, maybe this is where you're confused: if $B$ were Dedekind, $(0)$ is already prime.  Then Corollary 3.7 would say merely that $(0) = (0)$.  The remaining work just serves to show that $B\cong B$, which is true but doesn't tell us anything about the non-zero prime ideals of $B$.

Comment: Yes, I think that was my question. Thanks Slade.